# Missing content on website. Admins cant sign in

Tags: admin

Why has the content of our website disappeared? We have nothing. The site is still up but it is blank.
Help please.

Comment: Perhaps the pixies took it? But seriously, how can we possibly help you if this is all the information you give?

Comment: See the WordPress codex: [Common WordPress Errors](https://codex.wordpress.org/Common_WordPress_Errors) (Specifically the "White Screen of Death" section).

Answer (score 0):

Try disabling your plugins and then enabling them one by one. If you can't get to the WP admin bac kend, then rename the plugin folders on the server.